# Problems aligning div boxes with CSS Grid

Tags: html, wordpress, css, css-grid

I want to build a custom WordPress for my blog by using Grid and a Hero image.

This is my HTML:

```
    <div class="site-wrapper">

        <div class="section site-menu">MenuItem 1 | MenuItem 2 | MenuItem 3 | MenuItem 4</div>

  <div class="section site-header">
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="hero-content">
        <h1>If you can dream it, you can do it...</h1>
        <p class="subhead">lets do it !</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-right">This text should be positioned at the bottom right of the Hero Image</div>
    </div>
  </div>            

        <div class="section undefined">
            <div class="undefined-content">
                undefined
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section site-footer">Footer</div>

    </div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

.site-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.site-menu {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px 20px 9px;
    width: 100vw;
}

.hero {
    background-image: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/landscape-mountains-nature-clouds.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100wh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.hero-content {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-directon: column;
  margin: auto;
}
```

I have also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/ybog/pen/JrXKyv) for it.

I have multiple problems:

1. My Menu is wider than my image.
2. My text in the middle isn't align in the center of my Hero image and the `h1` and `<p class="subhead">` are side by side instead of among themselves.
3. `<div class="bottom-right">` isn't visible! I want to have it at the bottom right of the image and it should be on it.

Comment: Since your code use CSS Grid and not Flexbox, I edited your text accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I attached a codepen below with my changes.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

.site-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.site-menu {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px 20px 9px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.hero {
    background-image: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/landscape-mountains-nature-clouds.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100wh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.hero-content {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-directon: column;
  margin: auto;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -1.2em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

https://codepen.io/bartholomewdavid/pen/Xedjow

1) When using 100vw for the width it can cause issues. The reason is because its account for 100% of the viewport which includes the scrollbar. So 1 scroll bar of width was being added. I switched it to 100%

2) Centering the content in the flexbox wasn't working for a couple reasons.
The first is that there were two things being centered horizontally giving it that offset appearance.

I moved the .bottom-left component out of its parent and vertically offset it by a little bit to appear on top of the background image.

The final thing was the centered text appearing beside the sub heading. To fix that I just removed display: flex on it.

Comment: Is this a good practice to have the class `bottom-right` aligned at bottom right on the hero image by using `margin-top: -1.2em;`. Isn't there any other method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

.site-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.site-menu {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8px 20px 9px;
    width: 100%;
}

.hero {
    background-image: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/landscape-mountains-nature-clouds.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100wh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.hero-content {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```